# Is it possible to use the genitive with these expressions?

Tags: possessives

Why don't we say "cat's food' but "cat food", is it because the owner is not a human? Can we say pets' food?

Comment: "Cat" in "cat food" is a _noun adjunct_: a noun used to modify another noun. For more, have a look at **[this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/110438/37009)**. Also, there is nothing wrong with using the apostrophe-s (which we call the _"Saxon genitive"_) to indicate possession by non-humans or even inanimate objects. _"The food's taste"_ is perfectly grammatiocal and acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use "cat food" because it's not a genitive. "Cat" is a descriptor. It's the equivalent of "blue house" -  a house that is blue.

A can of "cat food" is a can of food for cats - generally, not a specific cat.

You can definitely say "cat's food" but you wouldn't use it to describe the food generally, you use it to describe it particularly. Here's an example.

> 1. My dog eats cat food.
> 2. My dog eats the cat's food.

These mean different things.  Version 1 means that I, for some reason, feed my dog cat food instead of dog food. Version 2 means that I have both a cat and a dog and the dog eats the food that's put out for the cat.