# "Title of the book" or "Book title"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm designing a form to enter book data.
Should I label the title field:

1. Title of the book
2. Book title

(I want to keep "book" in the labelling text)

1 seems too French (my native language) to me.

Comment: book title is fine because in English many  nouns behave adjectivally. You're designing a form for information on a book **to be entered** [by someone]. A form cannot enter data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what cases I should skip 's in possessive case?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110436/in-what-cases-i-should-skip-s-in-possessive-case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Book title" is perfectly fine and shorter.

Given the context (a data input form), I would go for the short option.